# Inferring return type from the rest parameter shape

Tags: typescript

So consider a set of transform functions that either take one argument and return a value or a function (of the same effect) which takes one or more arguments returning an array of values.

I don't want to implement a multi-function solution, e.g.

```ts
class A<T>  {
  transform(value: T): T { ... }
  transformMany(...values: T[]): T[] { ... }
}
```

An obvious solution is to fix the return as an array

```ts
Class A<T> {
  transform(...values: T[]): T[] { ... }
}
const a = new A<number>();
let one: number = a.transform(1)[0];
let many: number[] = a.transform(1,2,3);
```

but I find hardcoding the `[0]` unwise (and annoying).

Using `infer` yields a decent outcome

```ts
type TransformResultType<T> = T extends (infer R) ? R : T[];

class A<T>  {
  public transform<K extends T | T[] = T>(...values: T[]): TransformResultType<K> {
    const result: T[] = /* result of some transform */
    return (result.length ? result : result[0]) as TransformResultType<K>;
  }
}

const a: A<number> = new A<number>();
a.transform(1); // return type = number
a.transform<[]>(1, 2, 3); // return type = [] which is OK
```

However what I want is the return type to inferred by the shape of the call parameters rather than forcing the issue with `<[]>`.

What I want

```ts
a.transform(1); // return type = number
a.transform(1, 2, 3); // return type = number[]
```

Am I missing something or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: The problem here is that if you ever call your method like `a.transform(...args)` then the return type is going to depend on the length of `args` at runtime, which in general can't be known. Any solution without just having two separate methods is going to run into this problem, because you need the return type to be `number[]` when the argument is a tuple type (with known length) but `number | number[]` when the argument is an array type (with unknown length). Splitting this into two separate methods with different return types is the only sensible solution, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a function that returns a single value with one argument, and an array of values with more than one argument?

You can do this by inferring the arguments as a tuple, and then testing its length in a conditional type.

Something like:

```
type TransformResultType<T extends unknown[]> =
  T['length'] extends 1 ? T[number] : T

// test it
type A = TransformResultType<[1]> // 1
type A = TransformResultType<[1, 2, 3]> // [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that the type is not `number` and `number[]` it is `1` and `[1,2,3]`. They are constant tuples, but they should be assignable to `number` and `number[]`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

You now need to grab the whole array of arguments as the generic parameter, since you need the length. If you only infer the member type of the array, then you won't have that length.

```
class A<T>  {
  public transform<K extends T[]>(...values: K): TransformResultType<K> {
    const result: T[] = [] /* result of some transform */
    return (result.length ? result : result[0]) as TransformResultType<K>;
  }
}
```

Also note that the spread of arguments is *always* an array. So `K extends T[]` is the correct constraint for *all* arguments. `T | T[]` would allow for:

```
transform(1, 2, [4,5,6])
```

Which doesn't sound like what you want.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=13&ssc=50&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbAShFAVwBtgZwIAeGKCAD2AiQBMUpCkBrJDAdyQDaAXQB8UALwBYAFBRYAgOTEmAc2AALBUNoMmrKAEYoAfnlJC2AEYQ42gFywZMgMbEEKNgEFqYqAG8ZOTBCS2IAS2coYERUTBxKAGkdRhY2GGERAAoAOlyANwRiQgIHBIBKB3hkdCw8AhIyCkSxANk5KGcMVGAoOHrSSuEJKCGAegAqXv6ejDQoFAxsaGjquOwocdHA9r7gQjgkKEy+olJs5SQ1dRMp056HE4aBAAYhMqh3WBianHw78kgzQA3NsAL4ycHSFxdFA9BAObzmKw2MTiKBICC8KCIizWOBZMog6SdbrzMKXZTDBDZFaxWqZAyEqCjUaGaGk7ANMJgSlo6m0n7YBkAGigACZRQBmJkskYGYUSyVCIA)

---

This approach does have some limitations, however. If you can't know the number of arguments at compile time, then you can't know the return type.

```
const data: number[] = [1]
const weird = a.transform(...data) // number[]
```

This would cause a problem, because the function is typed to return an array here, but the function will return a single value. The correct return value in this case is `number | number[]` because the type system doesn't actually know which it will be. Then the caller can sort it out.

To fix that we have to do a bit more work.

```
type Exact<A, B> =
  A extends B ? B extends A ? A : true : false

type IsLengthKnown<T extends unknown[]> =
  Exact<T['length'], number>
```

`Exact` is a handy type to test if two types are exactly the same. `Exact<number, number>` is true, but `Exact<number, 1>` is false.

This is important because the length of an array is `number`, but the length of a tuple is some *specific* `number`. So `IsLengthKnown` will tell us if `T` is a tuple with a fixed length or an array.

```
type TupleHasLength = IsLengthKnown<[1,2,3]> // true
type ArrayHasLength = IsLengthKnown<number[]> // false
```

Lastly, we can change the `TranformResultType` to this:

```
type TransformResultType<T extends unknown[]> =
  T['length'] extends 1 ? T[number] // one argument, use the member type of T
  : IsLengthKnown<T> extends true ? T // more than one argument use T
  : T | T[number] // uknown length, use a union of both
```

Which now does this:

```
const a: A<number> = new A<number>();

const single = a.transform(1); // 1
const multiple = a.transform(1, 2, 3); // [1,2,3]

const dataArray: number[] = [1]
const singleDataArray = a.transform(...dataArray) // number | number[]

const dataSingle = [1] as const
const singleDataTuple = a.transform(...dataSingle) // 1
```

I believe that will be correct in all cases.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=10&ssc=59&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwMbADwEEA0UBCA+KAXgFgAoKKdKCOYCAOwBMBnXKAfjZrqdas6oAuKMABOAV2jCAZggA2zCGTKhIUAJLMAMgwDmwABYBpegHsA7vVQAVarQYso4+gGszlgNoBdAiXKxEFBsPAHI5PUMQr2x6cQBbACMIUTxlUlVoa1EEemZpU1E4gCUIZnE5YGtwCBs7HkdnNwt6b18yCmtQ8Pp9Ayi6h1YARg4oTtjE5K8oAHoZqFN6aARRXXiGYGxxRREDaDiISdERaoXpMfaKKGFNHR7DE2abAm5BkQloTls5qDiC6EMOQWSygKzWB3owCcO2slwowlsAB8xh4JklRNMfuImpYoN1elsdggnPQAJaLM5QBKmQxQNJIOQIZh8Z4UADelzA4gSclJSHeOTyBTiqCMA14KJ8AAoAHRygBu8kkzGERgAlAjsrl8oUSmUKlVIKKCBz-BQkItmFDRKVysAEd4iFBHTMAFRQG36qGmc7MUwHAXa4VQV0zOEeiDAcSiehQKWeu0y-G0zgJirXCNejwABi8atBrCygp1xVtBuqxoA3JcAL5kOukMgW3JQhDCdCoNHJXxQJbmSid+LovBStXV0jNq1QZiknrhJ0IGViYvCqVDMezeZDJuWqFxO2ksDzwigpdaoWFNfYABM2AAzBufh4hphb3evPTd1BGAhgAh0KI2QgMIXaiI6J7Ph+E5fjOc4QAAIr+-6AQgIALmeK6XnKMo-n+AFAfmPygVAyKgd4n4tt+SEAMqzrox7OkM0xMlAk7ADulGwfRCFIdY4hHtAJ6LsuQZYXKuEILRcGEVuQA)

---

All in all, always returning an array maybe be a better idea. As you can see it gets pretty hairy to handle all the edge cases. And as the consumer of this API, I think it's less cognitive load to know this function always accepts/returns an array, then to know there is a special case of one argument.

Comment: My only regret is that I have only one upvote to give this answer!

Comment: Wow, what a high quality answer!  Even though at the end this may not be the ultimate  choice - as you pointed out, cognitive load etc. - this answer has really expanded my knowledge, and does what I was looking for. Thank you!